# simple pedalboard, amp, AND DI box hookup?

Tags: audio, live-performance

I have a small pedalboard that I use with my JCM 2000 DSL amp and 4/12 cab. Till now I've only been using it for at home practice.I now have an opportunity to use this setup in a worship team band setting. The question is: can I use this pedalboard and amp with a DI box or do I really need to just think of using the DI/pedalboard without my amp (and with a speaker cab simulator instead) and just rely on stage monitors for on-stage sound? If I can use my home setup AND amp, do I run guitar into DI (1/4"), DI out (1/4") to pedalboard, and pedalboard out to Amp (1/4"), then XLR out of the DI to mixer? will that work? thanks

Answer (score 2):

You really want a 'power soak' or attenuator, something that lets the amp 'speak in its own voice'.
They usually have a DI point & speaker emulation.

The trouble is, most of them are really expensive. You can get them for as little as $£€ 60 but I don't know how good they are.
Examples from large EU box-shifter - https://www.thomann.de/gb/attenuators.html

Alternatively, you might consider a 'modelling' amp of some sort; reduce the whole rig to in effect just one pedal that does everything.
I'm only familiar with Line6, which I use myself, but there are hundreds of alternatives.
Again, EU box-shifter listing - https://www.thomann.de/gb/search_dir.html?sw=modelling%20amp&smcs=aa123d_3369